# How to locate React based elements using Selenium python

Tags: python, reactjs, selenium

The Source code for the react element looks like below:

```
<g transform="translate(0 80)" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 80px, 0px);">
 <g class="sc-hMrMfs bRtpcM">
  <rect class="sc-drlKqa gwqdPs" x="-40" y="-20" height="40" width="80" rx="20" ry="20">
  <path class="sc-bIqbHp fiTNSa" d=" M -8 -6.666666666666667 l -6.666666666666667 6.666666666666667 l 6.666666666666667 6.666666666666667 ">
  <path class="sc-bIqbHp fiTNSa" d=" M 8 -6.666666666666667 l 6.666666666666667 6.666666666666667 l -6.666666666666667 6.666666666666667 ">
  <path class="sc-bIqbHp fiTNSa" d="M -13.333333333333334 0 h 26.666666666666668">
  <rect class="sc-jxGEyO lfiaEG" x="-40" y="-20" height="40" width="80">
 </g>
</g>
```

I'm trying to locate and right click the below element

```
<rect class="sc-jxGEyO lfiaEG" x="-40" y="-20" height="40" width="80">
```

using

```
slider = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@transform="translate(0 80)"]/g/rect[2]')
ActionChains(driver).context_click(slider).perform()
```

but this doesn't seem to work. Is there a better way to locate such react based elements using selenium webdriver?

P.S : **The class name changes i.e is dynamic, so I can't use the class name in the xpath.**

Comment: It seem like you want to handle nodes inside `<svg>`. In such case you can try `'//*[name()="g" and @transform="translate(0 80)"]/*[name()="g"]/*[name()="rect"][2]'`

Comment: @Andersson : Thanks mate. It works. I've slightly modified the xpath to //*[@transform="translate(0 80)"]//*[name()="rect"][2] and it worked too. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

As we can see that the element which you are trying to locate is within `<g>` tag which is definately within a `<svg>` tag, so we can try the following `xpath`to locate the element:

```
"//*[name()='svg'//*[name()='g' and @transform='translate(0 80)']/*[name()='g']/*[name()='rect' and x='-40' and y='-20']"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can avoid dynamic class names for a specific class:

```
:global(.yourClassName) {
  ...
}
```

That way, your element will keep the correct class name and you can use the class name for your selection.

Source: https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules

Answer (score -1):

XPath has some limitations when used on a SVG DOM element. So you are better off using a CSS selector:

```
g[transform='translate(0 80)'] > g > rect:nth-child(2)
```